# Making some user as premium user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, payment-gateway

I am making ROR app and mongodb with devise. Now initially in app user are signed in with email , user name and password . When a user is logged in he is given option to upgrade to premium by making payment. How can I do that do that? One of the thought I have is will add one more optional field of premium into the user model and if person subscribed to premium I will raise the flag. Most probably I will use third party payment gateway like cc avenue. How ccavenue will let me know that payment has been made.

Answer (score 1):

You can read through their documentation before you sign up.  http://www.ccavenue.com/quick.jsp

Usually they will provide you with some kind of callback to tell you whether you have success or failure on the card.  Based on that information, you can update a column in your `User` table, or you could even have a separate table called `Payments` that contains all of the payment information (date, time, success, etc).  If you got that route, you can set up the `User` model to use `has_one` or `has_many` payments.

Comment: there is nothing mentioned of rails in it.

Comment: You can look at the other code and see if you can determine the callbacks, or you can contact their technical team and get them to help you.  If you need something with Rails support out of the box, obviously you will have to look elsewhere...